# How do I get multiple default values in properties across different profiles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a few microservices with the same configuration, with each depending on a Spring profile. `@ConfigurationProperties` takes the values that I have in my YAML application profile file. I want to move this configuration to a common project and out of the microservices YAML configuration.

The problem is that I have 2 different configurations for different profiles. I can use `@Value` to inject default values, but I can do that only once. Is there a way to have multiple default values contingent on a specific Spring profile?

In my project we use Java configuration, not XML.

Comment: Probably  Spring cloud config solve all your problems https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like below ? I have two profiles A1 & B1 with the same property (app.port) in the same yml file (application.yml). The profiles are separated by `---`

```
   ---
    spring:
      profiles: A1
    app.port: 8080
   ---
    spring:
      profiles: B1
    app.port: 9090
    ---
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read properties from **common location** then write `bootstrap.yml` in your microservices and delete `application.yml`.

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  config:
    location: file:/home/external/properties/location/
    name: application
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

file location: `/home/external/properties/location/`

suppose you need dev and prod environment.Then keep this 3 properties file in this location.

```
application.yml

application-dev.yml

application-prod.yml
```

Spring boot read `application.yml` properties first. If set active profile `dev` in `bootstrap.yml` then `application.yml` value **overwirte** by `application-dev.yml`.

For different value just change active profile in `bootstrap.yml` of your microservices.

Answer (score 0):

According to my search, I cannot resolve this issue as I want. Probably `spring-cloud-config` would resolve my problem but I don't want to implement this one. I changed the library and don't need to have these separate configs anymore.